# What is a better approach, less code and more ForeignKeys or more code and columns?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model, foreign-keys

I'm writing my first commercial Django app and I'm looking for some help as I'm stuck with changing and optimizing the models for quite some time.

Right now I'm considering what is the better approach to creating models. Let's say I have few models that all have few fields in common (like name, city, address, post code).

Can you tell me what is the better approach, repeat those few fields (columns) in every model (table) or just go for foreignkeys everywhere it fits and create an Address model even though those addresses will be of completely different things (people, institutions etc.) and I won't need them in one table.

I understand the more foreignkeys I make the more queries the app will make every time it needs some info from those other tables? Is it even worth considering?

The advantages I see are:

- less code
- not repeating myself

and disadvantages:

- more queries for the same information?
- little bit more complicated to implement later
- bigger possibility of duplicated rows

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you go for a base model and use FK to relate the specific information.

In a user example you could have a base model as you said and then a 'institution_profile' and a 'individual_profile' or something like that related to the user, and then just access all of them from the base model.

With this you will gain a LOT on readability and logic inside your code. Also you reduce redundancy on your database.

I also recommend checking [this article](https://www.scarydba.com/2015/09/09/yes-foreign-keys-help-performance/) about foreign keys performance.

Answer (score 0):

If i well understood your question, The logic approach for me is to define your fileds related to the model just once (model 1) , and if you want to use them and share them ( i mean fildes model 1) into others models you just create Join ( Foreignkey, many_to_many ...) between the other models and model 1.